# 'git remote' displays different url than set in .git/config

Tags: linux, git, github, git-remote

Yesterday started having weird issues with my github repos, when was suddenly prompted for user & passwd for push. Git is set up using ssh, and no changes have been made in months.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (push)

$ cat .git/config
 /-/
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:user/repo.git
/-/

$ git config remote.origin.url
git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

Re-setting via remote set-url doesn't change anything either.
No issues with bitbucket repos. Has there been some change I've missed?

Comment: It looks like everything is configured with github ?

Comment: Didn't find any related configuration on github account.

Comment: are your repos still created in github ?

Comment: Yes. As said, no (known) modifications have been done to either local nor remote repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gitconfig includes a config from one of the projects I'm currently working on. A new property was introduced I wasn't aware of:

```
[url "https://github.com/"]
    insteadOf = "git://github.com/"
```

Case closed.